# Listed as an author on conference submission page but not the paper

Tags: publications, conference, authorship

I worked with a group of professors on a paper that was submitted to a conference for publication. I was told at the beginning of the project and then several months before submission that I would be included as a coauthor. On the conference submission page, I appear as an author. On the manuscript that is being edited for final submission after acceptance, my name is not included. I am the only non-professor who worked on this project, so I feel a bit intimidated asking them why my name is not included. What should I do?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should ask them, as soon as possible, if you have been omitted accidentally. If you're being invited to edit the version for final acceptance it seems like you're being treated as if everyone assumes you're an author so a mistake seems most likely.

It gets much harder to correct past this point, don't wait. If you know one of the professors more than the others you could ask them directly rather than the whole group if that's less intimidating.